# Pagefile on D: partition being deleted after reboot

Tags: windows-10, memory, pagefile

There's not much free space on system (**C:**) partition in my laptop NVMe SSD, thus I set pagefile to only 1GB so Windows can still generate crash dumps, and 3GB on another partition (**D:**) in the same drive. However, the pagefile on this partition keeps being deleted after a reboot, no matter whether it's set to system managed or custom size.

Pagefile.sys is created at **D:** after setting up virtual memory, however it's gone after a reboot. I check Registry and the correspondent key is modified after setting and is not deleted after reboot, as expected, but I don't understand why Windows is still nuking the pagefile on this separate partition after a reboot.

I'm not much worried about performance because pagefile is essentially only accessed when using a hypervisor to run VMs along with a few browser tabs, I just want to prevent applications from crashing due to lack of memory. **E:** partition is an HDD, so it's not the ideal place to host a pagefile.

[image]

[image]

Here's relevant info:

OS: Windows 10 Home Single Language 19045.3031

RAM: 16GB

Comment: Have you by any chance enabled the grouppolicy [Shutdown: Clear virtual memory pagefile](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-clear-pagefile-on-shutdown/)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Windows Home SKUs don't have Group Policy Editor utility. Nevertheless, the correspondent registry key is already set to not clear pagefile.sys at shutdown, I mean,`ClearPageFileAtShutdown` DWORD value is 0.

I realy don't know why stubborn Windows is doing this, I really don't want to waste hours creating backups and then extend the system partition to acommodate a larger pagefile.

Comment: To be frank you've been kinda confusing. Is the problem actually that once you have rebooted, the settings you applied (on both `C:` and `D:`) would be reverted? Suppose that's a screenshot of "before reboot" in your post, can you add one of "after reboot"?

Comment: Which registry key is being changed ?

Comment: @TomYan I already found the solution, but the registry remained the same after a reboot, so did the Virtual Memory settings.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to set `PagefileOnOsVolume` key to `0`, and then I set the size of the page file to 1 GB on C: and 4 GB on D:, which is enough virtual memory for my needs at the moment.

> If you set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PagefileOnOsVolume` to `0` then reboot you will be able to set your page file to none on your OS drive and move it properly to another partition or HDD.

Source: [Move pagefile to another disk? (Windows keeps using C: disk instead of disk set)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/move-pagefile-to-another-disk-windows-keeps-using/b80fed24-12ff-4482-a45d-fdbae4f08987)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).